# Pre-populating an email address in Stripe / Checkout

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am using [Stripe](http://stripe.com) / [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) on a site in order to accept payments.  Stripe is fairly simple to use this way, as they give the following script to embed in web pages:

```
<form id="monthly" action="/subscribe" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_xxxxxxxxx"
    data-image="http://mywebsite.com/assets/img/logo_raw.png"
    data-name="My Website"
    data-description="Monthly Subscription"
    data-amount="6900"
    data-email="email@example.com"
    data-allow-remember-me=false
    data-label="Subscribe" >
  </script>
</form>
```

What I would like to be able to do is pre-populate the email address value (data-email="email@example.com") with a variable that I have in my custom.js jQuery script.  I am proficient with jQuery, but can I modify this embedded script with jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the [custom integration](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom), and do something like this:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

<script>
  var email = "customer@example.com"; // or use jQuery to dynamically populate the variable

  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_...',
    image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token) {
      // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
      // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
    }
  });

  $('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options:
    handler.open({
      name: 'Stripe.com',
      description: '2 widgets',
      amount: 2000,
      email: email
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation:
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.  I didn't even look at the custom integrations.

Comment: The problem I am running into now is the added complexity of using a custom integration.  Checkout was simple to set up: all I needed to do was supply the callback in "action" portion of the form.  It looks like with the custom script, I will need to do much more work server side.

Comment: Using simple vs. custom integration should not change anything server-side. The custom integration simply lets you call Checkout in JavaScript rather than with a HTML tag, and lets you define your own callback to do what you want with the resulting token.

Comment: How can i remove email field from custom checkout form

Comment: @Coder You can't. You can either pass a value as explained above, which will turn the field into a fixed label, or let the user fill the field themselves, but it's not possible to remove the field entirely.

Comment: @Ywain Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
data-email="email@example.com"
```

as mentioned in the question, works nowadays.

[image]